# Class with constants and methods

Tags: python

I'm writing a python module, and it is supposed to contain some constants, which I'm currently grouping in a class, like so:

```
(myModule.py)

class Colors:
    PURPLE = (0.549,0.110,0.706)
    GREEN = (0.188,0.463,0.165)
    BLUE = (0.125,0.247,0.600)
    ORANGE = (0.961,0.533,0.114)
```

So that, in my main program, I can use

```
(mainProgram.py)

import myModule as mm
niceColor = mm.Colors.PURPLE
```

So far, so good.

Now, I'd like to add a method to all the constant members of this class, so that I can call them like so:

```
brightColor = mm.Colors.PURPLE.lighten(0.8)
darkColor = mm.Colors.PURPLE.darken(0.6)
```

I know how to write the functions `lighten` and `darken`, but I'm in the dark as to where to add them to get the wanted functionality.

Many thanks

Comment: `mm.Colors.PURPLE.lighten` would raise an `AttributeError` since `Colors.PURPLE` is a `float`, not a `class` or `type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to have a class for this. Since you deal with tuples, your best solution is probably to extend `tuple` (or even better `namedtuple`):

```py
from collections import namedtuple

class Color(namedtuple("RGB", ["r", "g", "b"])):
    def apply_function(self, function):
        return Color(*map(function, self))

    def lighten(self, value):
        return self.apply_function(lambda x: x*(1+value))

    def darken(self, value):
        return self.apply_function(lambda x: x/(1+value))

class Colors:
    PURPLE = Color(0.549,0.110,0.706)
    GREEN = Color(0.188,0.463,0.165)
    BLUE = Color(0.125,0.247,0.600)
    ORANGE = Color(0.961,0.533,0.114)
```

You can then do:

```py
>>> print(Colors.PURPLE)
Color(r=0.549, g=0.11, b=0.706)
>>> light_purple = Colors.PURPLE.lighten(0.8)
>>> print(light_purple)
Color(r=0.9882000000000001, g=0.198, b=1.2708)
```

As you can see this is not perfect yet, as the `lighten` and `darken` methods are too simple, you'll just need to change the lambda passed to `apply_function` to have something cleaner (for example using a `min` to limit how large value can grow).

The advantage of having a `namedtuple` is that you can directly access any of the `r`, `g`, `b` from any color you have by calling, for example,  `light_purple.r`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class called color which has the method called lighten

```
class color:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def lighten(self, light):
        pass
```

and then instead of doing:

```
PURPLE = (0.549,0.110,0.706)
```

do

```
PURPLE = color((0.549,0.110,0.706))
```

In this way you should  be able to call the method from the color class

Comment: Just to mention, to access the actual color values, you'll either need to add more methods to the `color` class or access them as `mm.Colors.PURPLE.color`.

Comment: I believe OP was saying they wanted a tuple with a lighten and darken method, so that they could still access the base value without an extra method call.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @jotes answer - to get it to still act like the tuple you had originally when you're not calling darken, you could subclass `tuple` and add the functionality from there.

```py
class Color(tuple):
    def lighten(self):
        pass

    def darken(self):
        pass

class Colors:
    PURPLE = Color([0.549,0.110,0.706])
    # ...and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you the functionality you requested.  The `rgb` is a class attribute and `lighten` and `darken` are class methods which means you don't have to create in instance of a `Colors` object to do the lightening and darkening operations.

```
class Colors(object):

    @classmethod
    def lighten(cls, scale):
        return tuple([val * scale for val in cls.rgb]) # or whatever you need to do

    @classmethod
    def darken(cls, scale):
        return tuple([val * scale for val in cls.rgb]) # or whatever you need to do


class Purple(Colors):
    rgb = (0.549,0.110,0.706)


class Green(Colors):
    rgb = (0.188,0.463,0.165)


class Blue(Colors):
    rgb = (0.125,0.247,0.600)


class Orange(Colors):
    rgb = (0.961,0.533,0.114)
```

You can test it with something like the following:

```
print(Orange.lighten(0.5))
print(Orange.darken(1.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `NamedTuple`

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Color(NamedTuple):
    r: float
    g: float
    b: float

    def lighten(self):
        """perform lightening logic here"""
```